# What is this 3cm green caterpillar from northern California?

Tags: identification, caterpillar

We have a number of these caterpillars in the yard.  They are about 3 cm long.  This is on the peninsula south of San Francisco, CA, USA.  I initially thought of geometer moths but it seems to have the full complement of prolegs.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a [Cabbage looper](https://www.expressnews.com/lifestyle/home-garden/article/The-four-garden-pests-to-protect-against-now-12291153.php#photo-11659130), however I counts 4 (or even 5) pairs of false legs on your specimen, while it should be [3](https://aggie-horticulture.tamu.edu/galveston/images/GCMGA-8367_Cabbage_looper.GIF).

Comment: What is the plant it was found on? If it wasn't found on a plant,what plant was it near?

Comment: They haven't been on plants.  We have oak trees and California buckeyes in the yard plus rhododendrons, camellias, and other flowers. We haven't seen much damage.

Comment: @NiallC. If this insect doesn't affect the garden, why is this question not yet closed?

Comment: @AleksandarM If you think a question is off-topic, you can vote to close it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it may be an American Angle Shades moth caterpillar:

https://www.butterfliesandmoths.org/species/Euplexia-benesimilis
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euplexia_benesimilis
http://mothphotographersgroup.msstate.edu/species.php?hodges=9545

Answer (score 0):

[luna moth caterpillar](https://youtu.be/VKOLHOYPNzM)

This sure looks like your little guy!

Comment: That seems to be found from the great plains eastward, not in California

Answer (score 0):

The cabbage looper, *Trichoplusia ni*, is a moth, and has 3 pairs of prolegs.

The imported cabbage worm, *Pieris rapae*, is a butterfly, and has 5 pairs. The intensity of the coloration vaires with region and diet. I also see in other examples that the hindmost proleg is often smaller and almost vestigial, and might just be hard to see from the angle of your image. If you view another, look for that 5th leg!

But no matter which, they are a terrible nuisance to any cruciferous garden crop.

(I used mainly U of Florida for anatomical and taxonomic confirmation, but their photos aren't the best.)

Answer (score -1):

Its a cabbage worm. Those things are cool. They glow in the dark, and I dont mean reflect, I mean "Glow". At night they can be quite trippy, especially if your on mushrooms.

Comment: can you stick to the answer.   'It's a cabbage worm.' then tell us why it's a 'cabbage worm'.    What markings does it show to indicate to you this is the correct answer.    What information should the person asking the question know about 'Cabbage worm' other than they glow.  Do they eat cabbages?  What about other brassica, e.g. broccoli, cauliflower, brussel sprouts,...Finally leave off the part about mushrooms.  It has no barring on the answer.  It actual detracts from it.